# Integer concatenation issue in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have the following code:

```
function isValidAuthor($authorID){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM jos_users WHERE id=".$authorID;
    ...
}
```

`$authorID` is an integer, and is called from here:

```
if(!$this->_helper->isValidAuthor($settings['default_author']))
```

However, `$query` always ends up to be `SELECT * FROM #__users WHERE id=`.  I've tried casting `$authorID` to be a string, and have checked`$settings['default_author'])`, and it's what I want it to be.  How can I get the query to use `$authorID`?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a casting issue. Sounds like your variable isn't being set correctly somewhere.

Comment: The code works, the most likely scenario is just that `$authorID` does _not_ contain what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `echo $authorID;`

Most likely it's containing nothing in it....

Comment: You are correct, it was getting `unset` earlier in the code.  (Which shouldn't happen, but that's what you get for outsourcing).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function isValidAuthor($authorID){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM jos_users WHERE id='".$authorID."'";
    ...
}
```

Comment: That won't work, `$authorID` is an integer, and the issue is that it's not being passed correctly.